# Spring - find execution time of @Scheduled

Tags: java, spring, triggers, scheduled-tasks

I have a method in my bean, which executes periodically:

```java
@Scheduled(fixedRate = xx)
public void runPeriodically() {
    // do smt...
}
```

Now I want to find out the time of its previous execution. How can I do that? I read about `Trigger` interface, but it's not clear to me how to use it for my need.

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something, but wouldn't a simple instance variable do the job?

```
private Date lastRun;

@Scheduled(fixedRate = xx)
public void runPeriodically() {
   // do smt...
   lastRun = new Date();
}
```

As for the `Trigger` interface: you can't use `@Scheduled` in combination with the `Trigger` interface. At least not out of the box. If you want to use `Trigger`, you need to use a `TaskScheduler` and ["feed" it with `Trigger` objects](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html). E.g.

`scheduler.schedule(task, new CronTrigger("0 15 9-17 * * MON-FRI"));`

`CronTrigger` obviously implements `Trigger`, so you have all your interface methods there.

Comment: I think that you answer solves the problem, but with Trigger interface with TriggerContext I will have access to methods like lastCompletionTime, lastActualExecutionTime, and lastScheduledExecutionTime. So I would be really grateful if you can show me a working example of doing it with Trigger.